# How to add custom button in sales orders grid page in admin magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, plugin

I want to add a new custom button to the sales order grid pageactions, i was trying creating Plugin for `"Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar"` but in the grid containers this block is not used, so thats no work.

Instead the `pageactions.phtml` is used like the image shows.

[image: Example of the new button]

How can I add the button? with a LayoutProcessorPlugin?

**Very Important**: I want to restrict the button to users with access to a custom Access Role that I have created.

Comment: you can start by overriding `sales_order_grid`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following way:

**app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="CustomButton" class="SR\MagentoStackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\CustomButton"/>
        </buttons>
    </settings>
</listing>
```

**app/code/SR/MagentoStackExchange/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/CustomButton.php**

Here I have used **Magento_Cms::save** for ACL, replace your own.

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoStackExchange\Block\Adminhtml\Sales;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Control\ButtonProviderInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

class CustomButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    /**
     * @var Context
     */
    private $context;

    /**
     * CustomButton constructor.
     *
     * @param AuthorizationInterface $authorization
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization,
        Context $context
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
        if (!$this->authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Cms::save')) {
            return [];
        }

        return [
            'label' => __('Custom Button'),
            'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getBackUrl()),
            'class' => 'primary',
            'sort_order' => 10
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get URL for back (reset) button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBackUrl()
    {
        return $this->context->getUrlBuilder()->getUrl('sales/order_create/start', []);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here I want to create a modal when this button was clicked. So i have to pass this URL in this function 'onclick' => "",... Is there an idea from your side? @Sohel Rana

Comment: How to add two buttons any idea?